# Remove folder from MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins

I'm trying to remove a folder (well, actually I thought it was easier to remove the files inside it) from a build using MSBuild scripts.

I thought the way is removing them from the copy task itself, but what I was thinking it was going to see quite straightforward it's not working (I'm sure because I don't have much idea of this stuff, just read documentation yesterday and today). Here is how I'm trying to remove the folder (or the files inside it) ..App_Data/Email Templates with this space (does the space something to do?).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SourceRootFiles Include="$(BuildFolder)/**/*.*" Exclude="$(BuildFolder)/**/App_Data/Email Templates/*.*">
  </SourceRootFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrepareBuild" DependsOnTargets="CleanUp">
  <Message Text="Preparing the build directory : $(LocalBuild)"></Message>
  <MakeDir Directories="$(LocalBuild)" />

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceRootFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(LocalBuild)\%(RecursiveDir)">
  </Copy>
  <Exec Command="FOR /r &quot;$(LocalBuild)&quot; %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q &quot;%%f&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="PrepareBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(LocalBuild)\Getting.sln" />
</Target>
```

Update.

Jenkins is raising this error

:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error : Copying file App_Data\Email Templates\BuyerRegistrationComplete.htm to obj\Latest\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\Email Templates\BuyerRegistrationComplete.htm failed. Could not find a part of the path 'App_Data\Email Templates\BuyerRegistrationComplete.htm'. [C:\Builds\Getting\Latest\Build\Web\UI\UI.csproj]

Dont' really know if it's exluding it or not

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look very well formatted, don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On githup is a project named MsBuildTasks that contains all kind of custom-actions that you can easily integrate in your project

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

From your update tells a "new" story.

In your project-file you reference files in the App_Data folder which WebDeployment wants to copy to deployment. Removing App_Data results in missing files and thus failure.
Either move those files to another location in your project or remove the references to those files.

My suggestion would be to make a separate folder for the templates, App_Data has a different purpose.

Comment: Well, the script import that as far as I understand            <Import Project="Tasks\MSBuild.Community\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />